# Cancel AsyncHttpClient request during the task execution in the service

Tags: android

I use async http  android library [loopj](https://github.com/loopj/android-async-http)
to implement a file uploader service. It has the following simplified implementation

```
class MyService extends IntentService {


     private CompletionService<NoResultType> mEcs;
     private ExecutorService mExec;
     private final int THREADS_NUM = 5;
     private final  AsyncHttpClient aClient = new AsyncHttpClient();

            public interface UploadListener{
                void uploadFailed(final int position, int errorCode );
                void didUpload(final int position);
            }

            UploadListener   myUploadListener;

         MyService(){
              // Init CompletionService and ExecutorService is here
              mExec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(THREADS_NUM);
              mEcs = new ExecutorCompletionService<NoResultType>(mExec);
         }

         myUploadListener = new UploadListener{

           void uploadFailed(final int position, int errorCode ){
                if(isCriticalError(errorCode)){
                        aClient.cancelRequests(getApplicationContext(),true); // Cancel Upload process
                   mExec.shutdownNow(); // Stop Execution of upload tasks
                }
           }

         } // myUploadListener

             protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

             // Init tasks here
              ArrayList<File> fileList = gerFileList()
                ArrayList<UploadTask> tasks = new List
                  for (File file : fileList) {
                        UploadTask yt1 = new UploadTask(file.getId(), file);
                        tasks.add(yt1);
                    }

                    for (UploadTask t : tasks) {
                        mEcs.submit(t); // Start Task
                    }

            } // onHandleIntent

               class UploadTask implements Callable<NoResultType> {
                 public UploadTask(int position, MFile file) {
                        mPosition = position;
                        mFile = file;
                 }

                 @Override
                public NoResultType call() throws Exception {


                     aClient.post(getApplicationContext(),url,params,new AsyncHttpResponseHandler{

                       public void onFailure(Throwable e, String response) {

                           myUploadListener.uploadFailed(mPosition, getCode(response));

                      }

                 } ); //  aClient.post

                } // call()

            } // UploadTask
 } // MyService
```

The logic of this implementation is simple: Whenever the upload fails due to fatal error immediately cancel execution of other upload tasks. The problem is that it terminates execution of tasks, but it doesn't terminate uploading of a file in the task which has been started. 
For example, Upload Task `Starts  => aClient.post(file)`. Upload task is canceled. but upload process `aClient.post(file)` stays despite calling `aClient.cancelRequests(getApplicationContext(),true);`

Any Ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After googling a while I came up with a bit dummy solution:
In order to shut down the the request process just call

```
// aClient is an instance of AsyncHttpClient(SyncHttpClient)
  aClient.getHttpClient().getConnectionManager().shutdown();
```

it works like a charm :)

Comment: getConnectionManager() is deprecated now, any other solution?